# Docker Compose Bind Mount Fails When Using `image` vs `build`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My bind mount fails when using `image` vs `build` in Docker Compose. The first configuration fails while the second one works. When I say fail, I mean the container constantly restarts. It's the same exact config just one uses `image` while the other uses `build`. Any idea how to bind mount an `image`? I've tried adding `working_dir` to the `image` configuration but it does not fix issue.

```
nodejs:
  image: node:latest
  container_name: nodejs
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - ./volumes/nodejs:/usr/src/app/
```

This works:

```
nodejs:
  build: 
    context: .
    dockerfile: ${NODEJS_DOCKERFILE}
  container_name: nodejs
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    - ./volumes/nodejs:/usr/src/app
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

Dockerfile *${NODEJS_DOCKERFILE}*:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

Comment: Remove `restart: unless-stopped` from the failing configuration. This way it will just stop when it fails, and you can do `docker-compose logs` to see what went wrong.

Comment: If you're just trying to run Node against code that only exists on the host, would it be easier to run Node directly, without involving Docker at all?

Comment: @cornuz nothing in the logs. Blank logs. Viewed 'logs' in Docker Desktop and via the `docker-compose logs`.